# Form event when change opacity in C++ (Windows form application)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I need help.
Anyone know what is correct form event when changing the opacity in windows form application? 
Really appreaciate anyone help or tips.

Comment: There is no such event.  Given that the user can never modify the value himself, only your code can, there was no compelling reason to tell your code that it changed a property.  It ought to already know.  You can easily add the event yourself, it just takes discipline to fire the event after assigning the property.

Comment: so i guess i will make my own event like if opacity == 1 then ,,, right? 
Thank you hans